# Как реализовать ластик в Android?

Tags: android, graphics, android-canvas

Вообщем ближе к сути! У нас есть нарисована картинка на Canvas'е по верх которой будет нарисована пальцем линия, часть которой в последствии нужно будет стереть без потери картинки или же нарисован текст по вверх картинки и я хочу стереть его часть. Проще говоря нужно реализовать ластик который будет стирать только то что было отрисовано по вверх картинки. Как такое провернуть? Помогите пожалуйста добрые люди!

[image: Пример]

Answer (score 1):

Делаешь разные слои, отдельно хранишь свои картинки, манипулируя только с тем слоем, который предназначается для рисования. Соответственно, когда тебе надо что-то стереть, то смело вытираешь ненужное и собираешь картинку из всех слоев (чтобы не просесть по производительности, можно пересчитывать только изменившийся регион или изобрести какие-то маски).

С точки зрения информационного наполнения, рисование и стирание - это одна операция, просто в первом случае ты закрашиваешь картинку каким-то цветом, а во втором - прозрачностью или цветом фона. Следовательно, нужной информации, которую нужно "не трогать", нужно хранить где-то еще. Слои - самый простой способ.